# Cucumber fails to reads my feature files but not the steps or scenarios

Tags: cucumber

When i am running my feature file it fails to see any of my scenarios and steps and returns 
"0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s"

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, i am currently trying to run through the cucumber and cheese beginners guide and am stuck here. code below.

```
Feature: Adopting puppies

as a puppy lover
I want to adopt puppies
So they can chem my furniture


Senario: Adopting one puppy
  Given I am on the puppy adoption site
  When i click the View Details button
  And I click the Adopt Me button
  And I click the Complete the Adoption button
  And I enter "Cheezy" in the name field 
  And I enter "123 Main Street" in the address field 
  And I enter "cheezy@example.com" in the email field
  And I select "Credit card" from the pay with dropdown
  And I click the Place Order button
  Then I should see "Thank you for adopting a puppy!"
```

Comment: Add the code where you are setting the location of the feature files and glue code

Comment: One common problem would be executing from the wrong directory in the command line, but there could also be a problem with the set up. If we could know which language you are using in the back end, and an idea on some of the step code, we should have all the information we need to answer this, but at the moment, there isn't enough information to recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

i have been running everything via command prompt, so i decided to get the trial of ruby mine. Found the issue in 3 seconds....senario instead of scenario........